# Add custom field from foreign table and validate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, simple-form

I have two models, a user model and an agent model. A User has one/zero Agent. Each agent has a "code" like a promo code.

When a user signs up, they can optionally enter a agent code. When checking the form, if the user enters a code,  I have to check it based on the table "agents."

If the code is wrong, the form is not validated and an error appears, if the code is correct I associate the user with the agent.

#### User model (*user.rb*)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
    after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

    has_one :agent

    def set_default_role
        self.role ||= :user
    end

    devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         :confirmable,
         :lockable
end
```

#### Agent model (*agent.rb*)

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Migration between user and agent

```
class AddAgentToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_reference :users, :agent, index: true
        add_foreign_key :users, :agents
    end
end
```

#### User DB

- id
- email
- password,encrypted_password,...
- sign_in information (time,ip,...)
- agent_id

#### Agent DB

- id
- code
- name

How should I do this?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear, can you make it better by some example?

Comment: Include your controller code.

Comment: I use devise(https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user controller.

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you,

In `User` model add one extra attribute called `code`.

```
attr_accessor :code
```

and validate `:code` on `create` like, agent is present with expected code.

```
validates :code_validation, on: :create
def code_validation
  c = Agent.find_by_code(code)
  if c.present?
     self.agent = c
  else
    errors.add(:code, "Agent not found with this code")
  end  
end
```